# Python Crash Couse - Alien Invasion - ship not moving properly

Tags: python

I'm working through the book, following it step by step. The screen comes up, the ship .bmp shows up where it's supposed to. The problem is it doesn't move left or right, most of the time. When it does move, it only moves right, never left.  It flies to the bottom right corner and just stays there.  Not sure what is wrong with the code. Thanks in advance.

> alien_invasion.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    #Initialize game and create a screeen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((
        ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)



#Start the main loop for the game.
while True:
    gf.check_events(ship)
    ship.update()
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)
    #Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    
    # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    
    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
    
run_game()
```

> settings.py

```
class Settings():
"""A class to store all the settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (0,0, 90)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

> ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = screen
    
        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    
        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
    
        # Store a decimal value for the ship's center.
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
    
        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False 
        self.moving_left = False
    
    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on movement flags."""
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left < 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    
        # Update rect object from self.center.
        self.rect.centerx = self.center 
    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

> game_functions.py

```
import sys

import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    
def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False
    
def check_events(ship):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ship)
        
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)
        
        
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have found:

1. IndentationError: expected an indented block in (settings.py).

Wrong one (before):

```
class Settings():
"""A class to store all the settings for Alien Invasion."""

def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game's settings."""
    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_color = (0,0, 90)
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

the right one (after)

```
class Settings():
    #"""A class to store all the settings for Alien Invasion."""
    def __init__(self):
        # """Initialize the game's settings."""
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (0,0, 90)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. I copied it wrong. I have the indentation as stated in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the `update` method of `ship` class, you wrote:

```py
if self.moving_left and self.rect.left < 0:
    self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
```

It should be:

```py
if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
    self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
```